# Keras Error:The model cannot be compiled because it has no loss to optimize

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

When I was using Keras. I received a wired error:

**ValueError: The model cannot be compiled because it has no loss to optimize.**

Here is my code:

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(LSTM(
    input_shape=(None, 1),
    units=50,
    return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(LSTM(
    200,
    return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Dense(units=1))
model.add(Activation('linear'))

model.compile(lose='mse', optimizer='rmsprop')

# Step 3. Train model
model.fit(X_Training, Y_Training,
          batch_size=512,
          nb_epoch=5,
          validation_split=0.05)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

change `lose` to `loss` :

`model.compile(lose='mse', optimizer='rmsprop')`

***should be***

`model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='rmsprop')`

Comment: Hi friend,can you help me with this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53971563/kreasvalueerror-error-when-checking-input-expected-lstm-1-input-to-have-3-dim

Answer (score 2):

Well, you're passing `lose=` while you should be passing `loss=`

Comment: Don't you think just adding a comment and a closure vote of "off-topic because of a simple typographical" would be much better, especially considering that you are an established member of this community?